# Cannot get hidden-menu over div

Tags: html, css, z-index

I am struggling now for like 2-3 hours, to get the "hidden-nav" above divs.
z-index seems to be not working the way it should be.

Since, I cannot link JSFiddle, here is the whole code which I am struggling with. (tips would be appreciated, what is the common method here of sharing whole code.)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Barlow Condensed', sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.content-left {
  margin-left: 10rem;
  margin-top: 5rem;
}

.content-right {
  margin-left: 10rem;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}


/* NAVIGATION */

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 5rem 0rem 5rem 10rem;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: hsl(230, 29%, 20%);
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-right: 15rem;
}

li {
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin: 0rem 1.5rem;
}

.login {
  color: hsl(230, 11%, 40%);
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#hamburger {
  display: none;
}


/* LEFT SIDE*/

.new {
  background-color: hsl(230, 29%, 20%);
  padding: 2px 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.mono {
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: hsl(231, 7%, 65%);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: hsl(230, 29%, 20%);
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 1.5rem 0rem;
}

.planning {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: hsl(230, 11%, 40%);
  width: 50%;
}

button {
  background-color: hsl(0, 100%, 68%);
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 10px 25px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline-style: none;
  border: none;
  margin-top: 5rem;
  margin-right: 0.7rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* RIGHT SIDE */

.content-right img {
  position: relative;
  right: -100px;
}

.rectangle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 80%;
  top: -230px;
  right: -50px;
  background: #edf2f6;
  border-radius: 31px;
  z-index: -1;
}


/* HIDDEN NAV */

#hidden-nav {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 14px 8px 38px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 1rem;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: 99;
  opacity: 1;
}

#hidden-nav hr {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#hidden-nav ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  margin-right: 0rem;
  width: 100%;
}

#hidden-nav li {
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}

#hidden-nav .login {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .navigation {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 3rem 2rem 0rem 2rem;
  }
  nav {
    display: none;
  }
  #hamburger {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .content-right {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    margin-left: 1rem;
    height: 50%;
  }
  .content-right img {
    height: 65%;
  }
  .content-left {
    margin-left: 2rem;
    margin-right: 2rem;
    margin-top: 0rem;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
  .mono {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
  }
  button {
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    margin-top: 2rem;
    padding: 10px 20px;
  }
  .planning {
    width: 80%;
  }
  .rectangle {
    top: -150px;
    right: -50px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow+Condensed:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />


<ul id="hidden-nav" class="animate__animated animate__fadeIn">
  <li>Product (hid)</li>
  <li>Features (hid)</li>
  <li>Pricing (hid)</li>
  <hr>
  <li class="login">Login (hidden)</li>
</ul>
<div class="navigation">
  <img src="./images/logo.svg" alt="" id="logo">
  <img src="./images/icon-hamburger.svg" alt="" id="hamburger">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Product</li>
      <li>Features</li>
      <li>Pricing</li>
      <li><i class="fas fa-circle fa-sm login"></i></li>
      <li class="login">Login</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
</header>
<div class="container">
  <div class="rectangle">
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="content-right">
      <img src="./images/illustration-devices.svg" alt="" id="devices">

    </div>
    <div class="content-left">
      <span class="new">New</span>
      <span class="mono">Monograph Dashboard</span>

      <h1>Powerful insights into your team</h1>
      <p class="planning">Project planning and time tracking for agile teams</p>

      <button>Schedule a demo</button>
      <span class="mono">to see a preview</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I guess you are able to see the issue.

Normally, it will be displayed by clicking on a hamburger menu, I just removed the display: none; from the menu.

Comment: Try making .rectangle z-index:0 instead of  z-index:-1; It works on a stacking order so even if you make it z-index:1 and for the top element z:index:2.  I found a lot of times that negative z-index very buggy.

Comment: What do you mean above divs? Can you describe some more?

Comment: @Brian, still the same.

Comment: @HassanVoyeau, posted my code, take a look at it please.

Comment: I am looking at your code BUT I don't understand what you are wanting?

Comment: I would like to get the #hidden-menu over the elements. To make it above them, not behind, so it would cover other divs. I hope I am clear. :S

Comment: I am testing the code and it is above the other divs. What browser are you using?

Comment: I have tested it in Firefox, Chrome and Edge also. But I get the following: https://ibb.co/fF5y2RW

Comment: Remove opacity and see if that helps. See here https://coder-coder.com/z-index-isnt-working/

Comment: Seems like that didnt solve it either..I do not really understand..

Comment: Next step would be to recreate the problem using the smallest example. Create two divs called top and bottom and see if you can recreate the problem.

Comment: Have you tried placing the ul #hidden-nav inside a div and applying the z-index to the containing div instead

Comment: @HassanVoyeau I tried what you suggested, something is not right with this whole stuff. It acted strangely with two small test divs also.

Comment: "*Since, I cannot link JSFiddle*" Curiously, why can't you?

Comment: It's not enabled when you post here, you can only paste your code. Also shortened links are forbidden.

Comment: You can only post a JSFiddle link when you have included your code in the question, per the site rules. There shouldn't be anything preventing you from including a single JSFiddle link in your question now that it includes code.

Comment: As I can see it, your hidden div is already at a higher z-index than the rest of the page when I run your code snippet. So... looks like a no-repro situation to me. Add a background color of green or something obvious to your hidden div to see.

Comment: Looks like some mobile navigation? Have you tried adding `background-color` to `#hidden-nav`? not just the `box-shadow`, perhaps it's just a illusion that it is still under the other elements

Comment: You want ul with ID `#hidden-nav` to be ahead of other content, right?

Comment: @Mordecai Correct.

Comment: @95faf8e76605e973, seems like this was the issue, but I really do not understand why.

Comment: Your ul element is already over other contents. You cant notice it, because the background of ul element is transparent. To see/understand that, add background to ul element.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue, by adding background-color to the #hidden-nav.
For some reason, with the background color inherited, the navigation becomes transparent.

[image: With background color]

[image: Without background color]

Answer (score 0):

the solution is add style
#hidden-nav { background: #fff; }

and how to sharing whole code:

1. choose code in text editor <>
2. share links of style & script as tag html normal
   example:

Write them anywhere inside html block

codepen is like as jsfiddle site
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vb9uYBtqmeM